# How to display hexadecimal value in Objective C with leading 0x?

Tags: objective-c

How to display hexadecimal value in Objective C with leading 0x ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This link](http://www.webtechexpress.com/lessons/lesson-5-objective-c-basic-data-types-and-literal-constants) might help you. A quote from it suggests this:

> `%#x`

Answer (score 2):

i have found soln, its %#x.